# Touchegg on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 Dell XPS13 fails to recognise gestures

Tags: gnome, touchpad, synaptics, 15.10, touchegg

I recently switched from elementaryOS Freya to Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, but unfortunately touchegg doesn’t seem to work, though it did with Freya.

I installed the version from the official repositories and it starts up, but fails to recognise any gestures. I already tried some solutions posted here, like using `synclient` to disable three finger taps and clicks, as well as starting it with `touchegg &`

I believe this problem may be linked to this `geistest` error:

```
Device 41600 added
    attr "device name" = "SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen"
    attr "device id" = 41600
    attr "device touches" = 15
    attr "direct touch" = true
    attr "independent touch" = false
    attr "device X minimum" = 0.000000
    attr "device X maximum" = 2972.000000
    attr "device X resolution" = 10000.000000
    attr "device Y minimum" = 0.000000
    attr "device Y maximum" = 1680.000000
    attr "device Y resolution" = 10000.000000
Device 43936 added
    attr "device name" = "DLL060A:00 06CB:2734"
    attr "device id" = 43936
    attr "device touches" = 5
    attr "direct touch" = false
    attr "independent touch" = false
    attr "device X minimum" = 1.000000
    attr "device X maximum" = 4070.000000
    attr "device X resolution" = 41000.000000
    attr "device Y minimum" = 1.000000
    attr "device Y maximum" = 2472.000000
    attr "device Y resolution" = 41000.000000
error subscribing to gestures
error subscribing window 0x000000d4
```

Also `xinput` shows the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer          (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL060A:00 06CB:2734                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I hope there’s a solution to this problem, I miss my gestures. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same issue but on Arch Linux and in my case the answer was that [touchegg does not support libinput](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1580512#p1580512). Check if you have `libinput-debug-events` command - if you have and it shows events when you touch the screen then you have libinput installed and it is not compatible with touchegg.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have `libinput` by default. It is not related.